# IndexError - Python Scraping Script

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

I am learning python. I am trying to write a script that will scrape key data from certain cells a table on a webpage, ignoring other cells that I am not interested in.

The script I have written so far collects the first two rows of the table, however it then throws up an error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Scripts/scraper.py", line 36, in <module>
    mp3 = mp3_container[0]['href']
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is the code that I have written so far:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://XXX'

# opening up connecting,grabbing page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
url_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parser
url_soup = soup(url_html, "html.parser")

#download table
url_data = {}
url_table = url_soup.table
url_table_data = url_table.tbody.find_all("tr")

 
url_t_d = url_table_data[0]

#template for exacting and printing data

for url_t_d in url_table_data:
    artist_container = url_t_d.find_all("td", {"class":"artist"})
    artist = artist_container[0].text
    
    title_container = url_t_d.find_all("td", {"class":"title"})
    title = title_container[0].text
    
    year_container = url_t_d.find_all("td", {"class":"year"})
    year = year_container[0].text
    
    mp3_container = url_t_d.find_all("a", {"title":"MP3 sample"})
    mp3 = mp3_container[0]['href']
    
    article_container = url_t_d.find_all("td", {"class":"articleListInfo"})
    article_link =article_container[0].a['href']
    
    print("Artist: " + artist)
    print("Title: " + title)
    print("year: " + year)
    print("mp3: "+ mp3)
    print("link: " + article_link)
```

Can anyone suggest where I might be going wrong? Thanks

Comment: I can assume that not every `td` has an MP3 sample...
But really not much to answer without the URL

Comment: @Maxiboi Thanks, and yes that is the case. I guess I will need to add some sort of 'if' rule to the mp3 loop section to give it a value if an mp3 link is not present. Or is there an easier way of doing it?

Comment: @LearningPython yes, that might help. You could also use [try/except](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp) so that the program will not break and give errors

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by wrapping each line in the "for" statement in try/except, eg:

```
try:
    mp3_container = url_t_d.find_all("a", {"title":"MP3 sample"})
    mp3 = mp3_container[0]['href']
except:
    mp3 = "none"
```